# Find n column distance from starting of table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one calender made in HTML table structure. I want to find width gap from starting of the table to any n column starting vertical border. Check in the image what I need.

[image]

Comment: Can post `html` , `css` ?

Answer (score 1):

This will let you know it:

```
$('td:eq(5)').position().left + $('td:eq(5)').width()
```

You can use `.position().left` to check the td's left position in the table and add the current width of the target td, now you will get the final width.

```js
alert($('td:eq(5)').position().left + $('td:eq(5)').width());
```

```css
table{width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;}
td{border:solid 1px grey; height:200px; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('row:eq(1) td:eq(11)').position();
```

Will give you the coordinates of the 10th element. but it does not take borders into consideration.

If you need an exact width:

```
var totalWidth = 0;

$('row:eq(1) td:lt(11)').each(function(){
   totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
});
```